# Using a local ARM Template with New-AzureRMResource (Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/users/environments)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-devtest-labs

I am attempting to deploy a Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/users/environments resource which will contain a Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks resource and a Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets resource. I have those resources defined in an ARM template on my local machine (I do not have access to a private github or vsts to add as a repo to my DevTestLab).

I am wondering if it is possible to specify the path to my local ARM template as the armTemplateId for the Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/users/environments deploymentProperties?

I can't seem to find any other way to specify my ARM template for use in creating the Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/users/environments resource.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Azure DevTest Labs only support environments from a repository. It must be in a repo, not on the local machine.

You may create a feedback item [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/320373-devtest-labs) for this feature.